# How to you identify date ranges/intervals for specified values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a set of data that tells me the `owner` for something for each `date`, sample data below. There are some breaks in the `date` column.

```
|    owner    |    date     |
|-------------+-------------+
|  Samantha   |  2010-01-02 |
|  Max        |  2010-01-03 |
|  Max        |  2010-01-04 |
|  Max        |  2010-01-06 |
|  Max        |  2010-01-07 |
|  Conor      |  2010-01-08 |
|  Conor      |  2010-01-09 |
|  Conor      |  2010-01-10 |
|  Conor      |  2010-01-11 |
|  Abigail    |  2010-01-12 |
|  Abigail    |  2010-01-13 |
|  Abigail    |  2010-01-14 |
|  Abigail    |  2010-01-15 |
|  Max        |  2010-01-17 |
|  Max        |  2010-01-18 |
|  Abigail    |  2010-01-20 |
|  Conor      |  2010-01-21 |
```

I am trying to write a query that can capture date ranges for when each `owner's` interval.. such as

```
|    owner    |    start   |     end    |
|-------------+------------+------------+
|  Samantha   | 2010-01-02 | 2010-01-02 |
|  Max        | 2010-01-03 | 2010-01-04 |
|  Max        | 2010-01-06 | 2010-01-07 |
|  Conor      | 2010-01-08 | 2010-01-11 |
|  Abigail    | 2010-01-12 | 2010-01-15 |
|  Max        | 2010-01-17 | 2010-01-18 |
|  Abigail    | 2010-01-20 | 2010-01-20 |
|  Conor      | 2010-01-21 | 2010-01-21 |
```

I tried think of this using `min()` and `max()` but I am stuck. I feel like I need to use `lead()` and `lag()` but not sure how to use them to get the output I want. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happened to Jan 16th?  What about Jan 5?  Why is that assigned to Max?

Comment: @GordonLinoff mistake on my part. corrected to include the gap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical gaps-and-island problem. Here is one way to solve it using `row_number()`:

```
select owner, min(date) start, max(date) end
from (
    select 
        owner,
        row_number() over(order by date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by owner, order by date) rn2
    from mytable
) t
group by owner, rn1 - rn2
```

This works by ranking records by `date` over two different partitions (within the whole table and within groups having the same `owner`). The difference between the ranks gives you the group each record belongs to. You can run the inner query and look at the results to understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You want to solve it by subtracting a sequential value from the date and aggregating:

```
select owner, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by owner order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by owner, (date - seqnum * interval '1 day')
order by min(date);
```

The magic is that the sequence subtracted from the date is constant when the date values increment.